# In a html form in the password field value is not showing as password

Tags: html, forms

The password field in the html form i have created for my webpage is not displaying the value as password.Its displaying "..." instead of "Password".

This is the code...

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="success_wrapper">
        <div class="success">Contact form submitted!
            <br> <strong>Thank you For Registering</strong> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <label class="name">
            <input type="text" value="Name:">
            <br class="clear"> <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a valid name.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> 
        </label>
        <label class="email">
            <input type="text" value="E-mail:">
            <br class="clear"> <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a valid email address.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> 
        </label>
        <label class="phone">
            <input type="tel" value="Phone:">
            <br class="clear"> <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a valid phone number.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> 
        </label>
        <label class="password">
            <input type="Password" value="Password:">
            <br class="clear"> <span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span>
        </label>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="btns"><a data-type="submit" class="btn">sign in</a>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Am sure what you are looking for is `placeholder` attribute

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me, I copy pasted the code here:
http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/

And it works properly. 
Maybe the issue is because you used capitalized "Password" vs "password"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly, if you want "Password:" as placeholder text use attribute "placeholder" like

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password:">
```

It will work in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `placeholder="Password"` not `value="Password"`

Just Replace this line

```
<input type="Password" value="Password:">
```

With

```
<input type="Password" placeholder="Password">
```